# How do I fix pip install error even when trying to install from local archive?

Tags: python, pip

I'm getting an SSL error when trying to use pip install openpyxl. This is a work PC and we go through proxy. I have also installed other packages using this method `py -m pip install C:\Users\Lamar\Downloads\ <package file name>` with a local tar.gz file which worked fine but when trying to use `py -m pip install C:\Users\Lamar\Downloads\openpyxl-3.0.7.tar.gz` I get the same error even though as if I am using (`pip install openpyxl`). Before attempting this openpyxl I just installed `py -m pip install C:\Users\Lamar\Downloads\xlrd-2.0.1.tar.gz` with no problems, could someone explain to me how this is possible and how to correct it. I also have tried the "trusted host" approach but that gives a "Cannot connect to proxy" error.

Comment: Try extracting the tar file and running `setup.py`. I tmight have an install flag as well, so use that as well, the problem must be arising due to it's dependencies.
Alternatively you can also try installing the `whl` file from the link given [OpenPyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/#files), and then run `pip install <path_to_whl_file>`

Comment: Hey @CRishi Thanks for the help right after posting this I found a work around when trying to ```py -m pip install C:\Users\Lamar\Downloads\openpyxl-3.0.7.tar.gz ```  I would get this message:
```Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/et-xmlfile/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:``` 
So I went to that link and grabbed ```et_xmlfile-1.1.0.tar.gz``` then did the same process over again after that installed I tried ```py -m pip install C:\Users\Lamar\Downloads\openpyxl-3.0.7.tar.gz``` again and it installed with no problems.